# How to read binary file?

Tags: c#, windows, binary

I got .bin file from encoded. How can i open or read it with c#?

Thanks already.

Comment: Better questions beget better answers. What is the file supposed to look like? Structured data in Columns? Textual, binary values like INTs and FLOATs? What do you mean by 'encoded'. UUENCODE? Possibly we can help better if you shows some details from the OpenVMS angle. Try get us DIRECTORY/FULL output and/or DUMP/BLOCK=COUNT=1 and/or DUMP/RECORD=COUNT=3. Is there a DICTIONARY or some such to detail the layout?

Comment: Thanks Hein for your patiance and comment. Thats my fault and i edited the question with some details. Thanks already :)

Comment: Interesting, or "looks like fun" :-) The binary data seem to be VAX floating point data. As pointed out by Hein, you need to know which data format is used to make sense out of the binary data. Whether it is worth to convert or interpret the given floating point format in your C# program is another question. As you probably know, VAX floating point formats differ from the IEEE floating point formats. Converter routines exist on VMS, for example CVT$CONVERT_FLOAT, but there may be some sources for converters on the net, which you may want to use/look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the ".BIN" files and do not recognize anything in there to resemble a common OpenVMS data file. It looks highly application specific. There appears to be a header part with some recognible ASCII components, but after a few kilobytes the rest of the file is a blob of encoded/encrypted or compressed data, possibly with -1 (0xFF) bytes as 'record' seperators. Anyway, reading the bytes will be easy. Giving meaning to the bytes will be harder, and you'll need to speak to the folks owning the application and the file format to make sense out of it. This is too specific. No way a random reader here can help.

Now that we know these are list of floating point values we are perhaps getting a bit closer, but I still do not 'see' it. I do see series of byte values (offset 0x50000 )that almost look like floats to but I tried mapping them and no luck so far.
The definition of the OpenVMS specific floating point formats can be found in:
http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/73final/4515/4515pro_013.html

"what problem are you really trying to solve"? why on interpret, parse, reformat the data at the source?

Good luck,

Hein.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an instance of [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) in C# to open and read the files.

Notepad can open most files.

Without knowing more about the file format, or the application that produced it, there isn't much more that can be offered.